# Cannot make comments from facebook like button

Tags: facebook-like, blogs

I get the like button code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, and on my [page](https://davidshen84.appspot.com/blog/), the like button is rendered correctly...at least it looks like so :P

But when I click on the like button, the comment dialog appear and disappear immediately, and the button becomes a **Confirm** link; then I click on the like, a popup window ask me to confirm to like it...then, when I back to my page, I can see the comment dialog. But whatever I input, after I clicked on the *Post* button, the dialog will **not** close.

In my Chrome console, I see when I click on the *Post* button, a request is make to `https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like/comment`, and the return result is:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null}
```

I compared this behavior on other sites, and it is clear the return is different. But I have no idea why.

Comment: same happens to me when i put the like button on my tumblr. did anybody find a solution to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually that problem can be fixed by using an app id in the init code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

That´s Facebooks spam protection...

Comment: But I am not creating a FB app, I just want to have the *like* button. Can I just use my *userId* instead?

Comment: But I am not creating a FB app, I just want to have the *like* button. I tried to use my FB *userId*, does not work...instead, the button disappeared... :(

Comment: no, it has to be an app id. it´s quite easy to create one actually, you don´t need to program anything, just do some settings: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue and I am using an AppID. I've searched all over Google and StackExchange and other seem to have the issue too, but no one is offering a fix. Any ideas?

Comment: it´s also possible that the domain is well known for spam on facebook. is it your own domain or do you only use a subdomain of a bigger server?

Comment: @luschn, well...that's a big for testing...i am using `localhost` xD

Comment: it will only work if your localhost is accessible from facebook then. it´s not that easy with localhost, that´s why i recommend using a webhost even for testing.

Answer (score 0):

actually what **luschn** is right. you should create appID. facebook needs to count the LIKES when one clicks on it. you know, it's so simple. perhaps there's something you need to grab from the button :p

Try this stuff:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=null";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<span class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fb-name"  data-layout="button" data-action="like"></span>
```

appID set into null. This works, but it's spamming. This is just for experiments only.

Here's the sample page:
**http://developer.appacyber.net/feed/test.php**
It also works on localhost :D